# How can I convert my LINQ query to use the lambda syntax and is there any advantage to doing this?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple method:

```
    private IList<Objective> createObjectives()
    {

        var objectiveNames = new[]
        {
            "Objective 1",
            "Objective 2",
            "Objective 3",
            "Objective 4",
            "Objective 5",
            "Objective 6",
            "Objective 7",
            "Objective 8"
        };
        var objectives = from objectiveName in objectiveNames
                         select new Objective
                         {
                             Name = objectiveName,
                             Description = objectiveName + " Description",
                             ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                         };
        return objectives.ToList();
    }
```

Is this something I could convert to use lambdas and would there be any advantage in me doing this?

Comment: Among a million other reasons to use ReSharper, it can convert between the two styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objectiveNames.Select(o => new Objective
                         {
                             Name = o,
                             Description = o + " Description",
                             ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                         }).ToList();
```

It's hard to say what the advantange, but I prefer Lambdas, because I don't want sql-like coding in the program.

Comment: thanks but there is a problem and it does not work because the objectiveNames array does not have fields so it does not know about o.objectiveName.

Comment: replace "o.objectiveName" with "o" in Teddy's code and it should work.